# Python crashes on While loop

Tags: python, while-loop, crash, interpreter, pyscripter

I have had a really annoying bug since yesterday, when I reinstalled 
Python 3.2.5.
The bug was, that whenever I use a While loop the Interpreter of PyScripter crashes (and with that the whole program), but whenever I use it via Commandline `while 1: print("1")` it works just fine.
I've tryed this:

```
while 1:
    print("1")
```

and this:

```
i = 0
while i < 1000000:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
```

And both crash.
Any idea what to do there?!
I got it narrowed down to the while loop, but I still can't find the problem.
(Anyone alse have that?)
Any ideas? Looking for over 5 hrs now, still no idea how that happens...
The program DOES run, but after about 5 sec the program crashes.

Comment: what is the error output? (traceback / exit code)?

Comment: No there is not. It just crashes "PyScripter.exe stopped working" and "python.exe stopped working"

Comment: does it print `1` until crashing? does it write some wierd message?

Comment: Yes, it prints 1 until is crashes. No weird message. The usual windows "stopped working" message